# Modelagem de dados para tarefas favoritadas por usuários

Tags: modelagem

Tenho um aplicativo onde o usuário pode criar uma tarefa. A tarefa por sua vez pode ser pública ou privada. Se ela for pública, outros usuários podem vê-la e favorita-la. Ou seja, muitos usuários podem favoritar a mesma tarefa.

Eu pensei em criar uma terceira tabela, chamava Favoritos. Nessa tabela terei dois campos, `User_id` (que é o carinha que favoritou a tarefa) e `Task_id` (que é a tarefa favoritada.

Quando eu precisar mostrar isso eu filtro via código. Tá certo isso ou vocês me sugerem algo melhor?

Comment: Acho que é isso mesmo, coloque os dois campos como chave primária, e pense em criar um campo na tabela de tarefas para cachear um contador de vezes que foi favoritada, assim não precisa consultar e contar na segunda tabela e você consegue ordenar por favorita das mais facilmente...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Todo relacionamento que se entende como "muitos para muitos" precisa de uma tabela intermediária, como essa que você explicitou.

Nesse caso, como uma pessoa poderá favoritar diversas tarefas e uma tarefa pode ser favoritada por diversas pessoas, se faz necessário uma tabela de associação entre as duas entidades para que possa ser registrado esse comportamento.

Aconselho também colocar chave primária como a combinação dos 2 campos ( evitando assim que uma pessoa favorite a mesma tarefa mais de uma vez, supondo que isso não seja possível )
e uma coluna com a data em que o evento ocorreu, para fins de registro